# « À coller » sur le sticker

Tags: traduction

Il y a quelques jours j'ai reçu le papier justifiant la réception de ma demande (une démarche administrative).

J'ai remarqué que sur ce papier il y avait un petit sticker avec l'inscription ***« à coller »*** faite à la main. Le fonctionnaire l'a enlevée et m'a donné le papier justifiant de dépôt.

Normalement, je recevrai la réponse dans deux mois; je suis intrigué par cette inscription.
Qu'est-ce qu'elle peut dire ? J'ai trouvé deux traductions possibles dans mon dictionnaire :

- « à donner »
- « à refuser »

La deuxième me fait peur ! Pourriez-vous m'expliquer ce que cela peut signifier.

Comment: « À coller » ne se traduit ni par « à donner », ni par « à refuser ». Ça veut juste dire qu'il s'agit précisément d'un *sticker* qu'il faut coller quelque part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ici on est  plus dans le sens **« à donner »** mais en général dans l'administration, cela veut dire qu'on doit **coller quelque chose** à cet endroit.

J'espère que mon explication a été assez claire.

Comment: Donc, rien de figuratif ? :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Ça ne peut pas avoir de sens caché ici, non.